# How to add Social Account image to community Visualforce page?

Tags: community, profile, images

I'm setting up some custom Visualforce pages to be used in communities. When a user logs in, I want to use their image from the Social Account as a thumbnail image. But I can't seem to find the variable to be used as the image src.

What's the code I should use for the image src?

Answer (score 0):

On user Object you can find field `'FullPhotoUrl' and 'SmallPhotoUrl'`. You can use them to get the URL oof the user's profile picture

[User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)

Comment: I guess it's about social accounts and contacts not just photourl ..

Comment: @MohithShrivastava you mean FB, Twitter here. In that case he need integration. But i am not sure.

Comment: Social contacts in SFDC has those if you see .